# Any way to make the Github comment field monospaced?

Tags: github, github-issues

With Github being a hosting platform where you write technical things, I also found it very strange that their comment field is not monospaced (like on StackExchange).

Is there a convenient way to change that text field to have a monospace font?

Currently I often use the browser’s inspector (F12) to change the font, but maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now possible natively by customizing your settings: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-10-12-fixed-width-font-support-in-markdown-enabled-fields/

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely the easiest way to accomplish this nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

The web-extension [refined-github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github) does this, ever since [#1089](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/pull/1089). Installation links:

- [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/refined-github/hlepfoohegkhhmjieoechaddaejaokhf).
- [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refined-github-/).

Another monospace related feature's is included and that is [rendering text in `backticks` in issue titles, commit titles and more places](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/170270/55060505-31179b00-50a4-11e9-99a9-c3691ba38d66.png).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) to target the relevant input elements and apply your styling of choice. If you don't already have one, [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) is a very popular userscript manager.

Here's an example which you can configure:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        GitHub: Monospaced textareas
// @version     1.0.0
// @description Set the textarea inputs on GitHub.com to use a monospaced font
// @license     MIT
// @author      Jesse Jackson
// @match       https://github.com/*
// @namespace   https://github.com/jsejcksn
// @noframes
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

(() => {
  'use strict';

  const styleElements = (querySelectorString, styleDeclarations) => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(querySelectorString);
    elements.forEach(element => {
      for (const declaration of styleDeclarations) {
        element.style.setProperty(...declaration);
      }
    });
  };

  const styleDeclarations = [
    ['font-family', 'monospace'],
  ];

  styleElements('textarea', styleDeclarations);
})();
```